# How can I get the socket.id of a user when they connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to broadcast a message to a user when they connect but only to that one user. 
How do I get their socket ID when they connect so I can use `io.to(theirSocketID).emit('chat message', 'Welcome');`?

Comment: you need to store the socket everytime user connect to socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the data everytime a user is connected in an array

```
  var clients = [];

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("new user connected");
  socket.on("new user", function (data) {
    // console.log(clients[data])
    if (data in clients) {
      let index = clients.indexOf(data);
      if (index !== -1) {
        clients.splice(index, 1);
      }
      socket.nickname = data;
      clients[socket.nickname] = socket;
    } else {
      socket.nickname = data;
      clients[socket.nickname] = socket;
    }
    console.log("new user : " + socket.nickname);
  });
```

and on disconnect

```
 socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("user disconnected");
    delete clients[socket.nickname];
  });
```

that is what i always do to store the socket id for private messaging

this is what my chat socket look like

```
socket.on("chat", function (data) {
    var id = data.id;
    if (clients.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      io.to(clients[id]["id"]).emit("chat", data);
      console.log(clients[id]["id"]);
    } else {
      console.log("\nTarget Device Is Offline or Doesn't exist\n ");
  });
```

you can also implement read / unread if target is connected or not